# Convert string to double, but the first character is a dot

Tags: c#, string, double

I need to convert a string value similar to `.904` and `-.904` to a double. I haven't found any simple and direct way to do so, except to copy each character to another string and manually add the zero and then covert to double.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: How does copying characters to a *string* result in a *double*?

Comment: I could first copy the original-with-dot-first-string to another string and then convert it to double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure to specify a culture that supports that format when trying to convert from string to double, for example the culture-independent format `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        HandleSource("-.904");
        HandleSource(".904");
    }
    
    public static void HandleSource(string src)
    {
        double d = Double.Parse(src, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ftlYFE

When you don't specify an explicit culture and get the "Input string was not in a correct format" exception, this is because you run the code in an environment with a culture that uses comma as decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert with the help of Convert.ToDouble function.

The small demo link I am attaching for your [reference](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bcBdmS).

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I did tried this method and keep getting this error ```Iput string was not in a correct format```

Comment: What operation are you performing on resulted value?

Comment: ```double newValue= Convert.ToDouble(p.valueString);```

Comment: Can you please share detail code for review, as it's confusing to determine what is p?

Comment: You should put the code from that demo in the answer itself, too, to avoid link rot.

Comment: The exception "Input string was not in a correct format" suggests that you run the code in an environment, where the default culture expects a comma as the decimal separator. To use dot as decimal separator, specify a culture that expects that. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks @NineBerry . Your answer is informative. I am upvoting.